# Converting jQuery function to AngularJS approach

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am looking to migrate a Jquery Ajax form to AngularJS and I am stuck on the following process...

My form has several checkboxes grouped into categories; as some items span several categories there will be several instances of a product.

If the User ticks Product 123 in Category A, then Product 123 in Category C would also be ticked as they are the same product - equally they would deselect all instances...

My JQuery was fairly straightforward as below:

```
$(".checkbox input").on("click",function() { 
  $(":checkbox[value='"+ $(this).val() +"']").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked")); 
});
```

A simple scan of the DOM and to change the state of any checkbox with the same value assigned.

My AngularJS form is now in a state where via a metadata service I am rendering the form visually the same as my jquery version - so all products are correctly categorised and I am assigning the values to the checkboxes.

Can anyone assist in how I'd convert my Jquery function to angular principle?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282487/integrating-angularjs-with-jquery/28282615#28282615

Comment: Ok thanks for a quick reply - so that link seems to refer to calling an existing jQuery function from angular. In my case should I instead be looking to replicate that functionality in angular methods? I am just learning angular but I was expecting to instead be monitoring the Model for changes (as the checkboxes update the model) and not to be monitoring the dom as I was doing with jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate approach to tackle this requirement in Angular would be to bind all checkboxes related to the same product to the same ngModel variable. This way, the 2-way binding of Angular will make sure their state is maintained in sync at all times and you wouldn't need your jQuery code to do that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment and I understand your suggestion and how that will help, I just need to understand how I can achieve that with my current angular setup. I have no control over the JSON service but that defines the structure and I ng-repeat through it so the JSON contains the duplicate nodes - how would I be able to adapt that and say this checkbox already exisits so bind this field to the "master" field. Thanks

Comment: So given that every object has a unique identifier (allowing your to identify multiple instances of the same object in the JSON data), you can create a local model holding a single instance of each object and feed it to the view. This way, different instances of the same object would refer to the same object in your model. In Angular, I'd query the back-end to fetch the JSON data in a service and then have a service to handle the processing of the JSON and creation of the local model. Your controller would use this service to get the model and prepare it for the view.